# How to get nth-child number of a element

Tags: jquery, class, count, indexing, css-selectors

I don't need the `.index()` value.

Eg. when i have a list like:

```
<ul>
    <li class="alpha"></li>
    <li class="alpha"></li>
    <li class="alpha"></li>
    <li class="beta"></li>
    <li class="alpha"></li>
    <li class="beta"></li>
    <li class="beta"></li>
    <li class="alpha"></li>
    <li class="beta"></li>
    <li class="beta"></li>
</ul>
```

i need to get the order number by each class, and ignore the another class in the index count list, so i need something that work like this:

```
jQuery('ul li').not('.beta').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).text(get nth-child(THIS NUMBER) here);
});
```

and then the result would be like

```
<ul>
    <li class="alpha">1</li>
    <li class="alpha">2</li>
    <li class="alpha">3</li>
    <li class="beta"></li>
    <li class="alpha">4</li>
    <li class="beta"></li>
    <li class="beta"></li>
    <li class="alpha">5</li>
    <li class="beta"></li>
    <li class="beta"></li>
</ul>
```

i could do the same with the other class, like:

```
jQuery('ul li').not('.alpha').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).text(get nth-child(THIS NUMBER) here);
});
```

and this is the result

```
<ul>
    <li class="alpha"></li>
    <li class="alpha"></li>
    <li class="alpha"></li>
    <li class="beta">1</li>
    <li class="alpha"></li>
    <li class="beta">2</li>
    <li class="beta">3</li>
    <li class="alpha"></li>
    <li class="beta">4</li>
    <li class="beta">5</li>
</ul>
```

Please suggest

Comment: Why use `.not('.beta')` instead of `.alpha`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `each()` function has an index value: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
jQuery('ul li').not('.beta').each(function(index){
    var count = index + 1;
    jQuery(this).text(count);
});
```

Comment: great, i didnt know i could use it like this. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Simply use this :

```
jQuery('ul li').not('.beta').text(function(i){
    return i+1;
})
```

You can pass a function to `.text()`. In that function, the first argument is the index of the element in the stack. Since it is based on a 0-index, you need to add 1 before returning it!

Here a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wqLXA/1/

Also, instead of using `.not`, you could directly use `$(.alpha)` or `$('.beta')`. That would accelerate the process.

Answer (score 0):

Because each provides an index you can add to it to get the nth-child number -

```
jQuery('ul li').not('.beta').each(function(index){
    var nth = index + 1; // because of zero based indexes 
    jQuery(this).text(nth);
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/3eYQS/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a different count on the same function but for different classes (basically a separate count for beta and alpha at the same time in your sample case), try this:

```
jQuery('ul li').each(function(){
    var $current = jQuery(this);
    $current.text((jQuery('ul li.' + $current.attr('class')).index($current) + 1));
});
```

This will give you a result like:

```
<ul>
    <li class="alpha">1</li>
    <li class="alpha">2</li>
    <li class="alpha">3</li>
    <li class="beta">1</li>
    <li class="alpha">4</li>
    <li class="beta">2</li>
    <li class="beta">3</li>
    <li class="alpha">5</li>
    <li class="beta">4</li>
    <li class="beta">5</li>
</ul>
```

**<kbd>[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/yFLgR/2/)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

```
var index=1;
$('ul li').not('.alpha').each(function(){   
    $(this).text(index);
    index=index+1;
});
```